# How to parse the returned string?

Tags: java, regex

How to parse the returned string to get the key and value of each pair, and put it all in the collection?What kind of regex use?

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Продукт {" +
           " Название продукта = '" + _productName + '\'' +
           ", Код продукта = '" + _productCode + '\'' +
           ", Марка металла = '" + _brandMetal + '\'' +
           ", Вес продукта = " + _weight +
           '}';
}
```

like this:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Название продукта = " + this.GetProductName() + ";" + " Код продукта = " + this.GetProductCode() + ";" + " Марка металла = " + this.GetBrandMetal() + ";" + " Вес продукта = " + this.GetWeightOfProduct() + ";";
    }
```

Comment: Don't do that. Expose the field values through getters.

Comment: Yes, you should use getters instead of parsing the returned string

Comment: `toString` is mostly for developer use, when debugging. Don't use for structured encoding of the object. Besides, why stringify it, just to parse it again, when you have getter methods for retrieving the values?

Comment: Given that string format, how would you like the resulting collection structured? What will be the item type of the collection?

Comment: Thank you for help,now i use it like this

Comment: Without any form of escaping, the names will become unparsable when it contains the delimiter `'`.